# JQuery UI Multiselect with Knockout JS - data-binding with a helper plugin

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-multiselect

I'm trying to implement [jQuery UI Multiselect](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) with a KnockoutJS binding. I guess it cannot be done natively, which is why [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/ssajous/5823594) was made.

I'm using the plugin. I create my multiselect in php code but the output html is this:

```
<select id="multiselectpoc" data-bind="multiselect  : { config : multiSelectConfig,
            options: _categories,
            optionsText: '_name',
            optionsValue: '_id',
            value: selectedCategory,
            optionsCaption: 'CATEGORY'}" title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5" style="display: none;">
        </select>
```

I know that creating it in php is not the issue because I create other `<select>`'s in php that are not jqueryUI Multiselects, and the data-bindings for them work.

Here is my View Model (I use typescript):

```
class SearchFilterViewModel {
    multiSelectConfig = {};
    _countriesList = [];
    _regionsList = [];
    _countries = ko.observableArray();
    _regions = ko.observableArray();
    _categories = ko.observableArray([
        new Category(name="Meat-Free Meat", 1),
        new Category(name="Dairy-Free Dairy", 2),
        new Category(name="Confectionery", 3),
        new Category(name="Baking", 4),
        new Category(name="Dessert", 5)
    ]);
    selectedCountry = ko.observable();
    selectedCity:  KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable('');
    selectedCategory:  KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable('');

    constructor(allCountries) {
        for (var index = 0; index < allCountries.length; index++) {
            this._countriesList.push(allCountries[index]);
        }
        this._countries(this._countriesList);
        this.selectedCountry.subscribe(this.updateCities.bind(this))
    }

    updateCities(geonameId) {
        var self = this;
        self._regionsList = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: `http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=${geonameId}&username=elion`
        }).then(function(allCitiesXML) {
            var allCitiesJSON = xml2json(allCitiesXML);
            var allCities = JSON.parse(allCitiesJSON);
            for (var index = 1; index < allCities.geonames.length - 1; index++) {
                self._regionsList.push(allCities.geonames[index].geoname);
            }
            self._regions(self._regionsList);
            });
    }
}

class Category {
    _name:  KnockoutObservable<string>;
    _id:    KnockoutObservable<number>;

    constructor(name, id) {
        this._name = ko.observable(name);
        this._id = ko.observable(id);
    }
}



$(document).ready(function() {
    var _searchFilterViewModel: SearchFilterViewModel = new SearchFilterViewModel(allCountries);
    var _searchFilterForm = $("#find-vegan-products-page").find("form")[0];
    ko.applyBindings(_searchFilterViewModel, _searchFilterForm);
    $('.select-multiple').each(function(i, obj) {
        //obj[i] gets each element inside the div
        $(this).multiselect();
    })
});
```

This question is mainly about how to configure the empty `multiSelectConfig` object in the viewmodel. When I run the page in a web browser, the output html in the `<select>` is now many `<li>` tags that contain a fair bit of jquery ui multiselect code, but the bit that matters is that inside each `<option></option>` is `<span>[object Object]</span>` which is inside each `<li>` tag. There are the same number of `<li>` tags as categories, which makes me think the data binding is working. I just need to tap into the [object object] to get the properties (category.name). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably run through the KnockoutJS tutorials. AFAICT you're not currently really using it.

The binding handler is responsible for calling `multiselect(...)` on your DOM. You should not be calling it yourself like you are doing now. Instead, you need a view model that passes all information to the custom binding handler.

The binding handler expects a `config` as input, and your view is telling it that your view model has a `multiSelectConfig` property that contains that info. The binding handler probably crashes because your view model lacks that property.

Put differently, the binding handler you have assumes your view models has observables (or at least properties) named:

- `multiSelectConfig`
- `_categories` with a `_name` and `_id` property each
- `selectedCategory`

You haven't shown your view model code or KO bootstrapping code, but you'll need that to get things running. For example:

```
$(function(){
    var vm = {
        multiSelectConfig: { /* config here */ },
        _categories: [{_id: 1, _name: "test"},
        selectedCategory: ko.observable()
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

This code glances over a lot of important concepts, e.g. constructor functions for view models, observable arrays, mapping your json to the view model, etc., so again I recommend checking out the KO website and its tutorials.

Comment: Thanks. Very good info. Just added my view model to the question. I am currently thinking how to add the multiSelectConfig to my view model. If it is a ko.observable or just an object.

Comment: It can be a static object: the `init` in your custom binding handler will only read it once, at the start, and not observe any changes to the config. So a public property on your `SearchFilterViewModel` will do the trick. Start with `this.multiSelectConfig = {}` or something alike and you'll be up and running quick enough.

Comment: Thanks. All I have done is add the empty object called `multiSelectConfig` to the view model. The view shows [object object] for each option now (much better than before). Is my html output in my question correct? Am I just supposed to add some code to the `multiSelectConfig` in the view model?

Answer (score 0):

This is styled using bootstrap due to my css, this does not need this and does not have any dependencies.

```
<div class="input-group-lg input-group-xl">
     <select class="form-control needsclick" data-bind="options: ovariesJSON, selectedOptions: RightOvaryIDs, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', optionsCaption: 'Select'" multiple="true"></select>
</div>
```

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html

Their example:

```
<p>
    Choose some countries you'd like to visit: 
    <select data-bind="options: availableCountries, selectedOptions: chosenCountries" size="5" multiple="true"></select>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']),
        chosenCountries : ko.observableArray(['Germany']) // Initially, only Germany is selected
    };

    // ... then later ...
    viewModel.chosenCountries.push('France'); // Now France is selected too
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I need the select element to have a fixed height (then drop down with the options), so the standard html select will not work.